# How to deploy an already deployed build to another nexus repository?

Tags: maven, deployment, build, nexus, redeploy

We have a nexus repository environment that serves for multiple projects. 
Each project has a repository group which includes

- 3rdParty
- snapshot
- test (release typed repo)

Projects prepare builds for testing which are deployed on test repository. 
**What we would like to do is to re-deploy a specific version, which is already deployed on test repository, to a Releases repository on another nexus instance.** By this way only tested builds can be reached by customers.

**Is there a way to do that without performing another build?** Some builds may take up more than 3 hours and also it is  risky to perform another build.
I've searched and come up with wagon plugin but I am not sure about it. 
This operation should also perform skip/merge capability (may be fail never?). Because for a bug-fix release, most of the artifacts may not be changed. Thus; skipping those artifacts will save time in delivery.

Below scenario would be perfect:

1. Build the project and deploy to the test repository
2. Perform tests using test repository
3. Tests passed, re-deploy system version 1.0.1 (including child components) to releases repository.
4. Customer can only see tested versions from releases repository (1.0.1, 1.0.7 etc)

Notes:

- using snapshot for test builds is not an option :(

Thanx in adv.
Sincerly;
Metan

Comment: Simply buy an professional license of Nexus which supports staging which is exactly what you need but within a single Nexus.

Comment: thank you @khmarbaise. Is there a free way to do that? :)